# Local admin in xampp is redirecting to live site

Tags: xampp

I have downloaded the live site and setup a local host in xampp. The localhost frontend is fine, but when I go to the admin (local) the browser redirects to the live site. What do I need to fix?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? Removed everything in ./var/cache?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove cache, *sessions* and *locks* from the `var` folder.
2. After that check `core_config_data` for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in your db to see if they match the url you are accessing in your *local*.